# Wrapper For C Static Library

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I Have is C Static Library for Camera. Now Plan is to develop C#/WPF UI for Windows 8 which will use the C static library to capture video/Audio.

I came with the idea that there will C++/CLI wrapper for the C Static.The Wrapper will be Managed Dll.

C#/WPF UI will use this Dll to Capture the Video/Audio.

I wanted to Know whether this approach will be good.

Alternate Suggestion is welcome.Please Guys Suggest on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a very common solution to the problem. It is generally much easier to do it this way than using P/invoke.

Both approaches require you to wrap the static library. So you are almost certainly better off using C++/CLI for that wrapper since that is much easier to connect to your C# code than P/invoke.

Comment: So You Mean this is good approch to go.What about PInvoke ??.Whether PInvoke Support Static Lib.

Comment: can't p/invoke static lib, can only p/invoke DLL, C++/CLI wrapper is the way to go, just as you suggest

Comment: @Chris_vr - This is a common approach and an alternative to PInvoke.  Both solutions can do the job.  Pick the one that best works for you.

Comment: The C++/CLI approach for this case is portable only on Windows platforms.

Comment: @Luca The question explicitly talks about Windows 8 and WPF.