# Pinvoking functions from a static C library

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a native C++ library (static i.e. .lib target). I wish to use some of the functions in this file in my C# projects. For dlls, I could pinvoke them. How do I do this for static libraries?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821123/wrapper-for-c-static-library) and there David's answer says you can pinvoke only for dlls and not for libs.

Comment: David is correct. If you want to call a lib, you must first create a DLL (using C++). Then you can PInvoke that DLL.

Comment: So, this would mean, creating a dll (acting as a middle layer) which calls this .lib's functions and then pinvoking the dll function from c#?

Comment: Yes. A lib is not an executable. There is no way to "call it". You must create an executable (dll) from the lib first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static library is used by linking it into a larger module. In Windows that means a DLL or an executable.

They do not stand alone and only make sense when you link them into a larger module. So, that would imply that, in order to use pinvoke you need to build a DLL which includes the library, and pinvoke to that DLL.

As an alternative to pinvoke, you could make a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly. Link the static library to that C++/CLI assembly and expose the functionality via a C++ managed class. That managed class can then be consumed by your C# code.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, what was the use of making that C++ project a .lib in the first place rather than a .dll? If the solution contained only c++ projects, then calling functions from a .lib or a .dll is possible? So, why not just make .dlls always

Comment: It allows a consumer to build the code into a single executable and so not need to re-distribute auxiliary DLLs.

Comment: The alternative you mention is sadly not always possible I guess. A static library built with `\MT` flag cannot be linked within C++ `/clr` project. You will get _error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value '**MTd**_StaticDebug' doesn't match value '**MDd**_StaticDebug'_. To fix that you must put the C++/CLI project in `\MD` mode but you can't. You will get the error that _'/MT' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible_ So to summary, it will **only work if your native lib has been build with `\MD` flag** (dynamically link to the runtime).